# How do I clear controls when using required field validator?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I have a form with a number of textboxes and dropdownlist .. I have a clear Button which upon clicking is supposed to clear all the fields. But since i have required field validators and regular expressions validator on the form I am not able to fire click event unless all validation are satisfied.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`CausesValidation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.causesvalidation.aspx) property

```
<asp:Button ID="BtnClearForm"
                Text="clear form"
                CausesValidation="False"
                OnClick="BtnClearForm_Click"
                runat="server"/>
```

Another option is to use javascript to [clear your inputs](http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-reset-form.phtml).

Answer (score 0):

Set the CausesValidation property for the clear button to false.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

**CausesValidation** of clear button must be **false**.